# How to write this function properly? It gives me out of memory every time

Tags: c#, datetime, while-loop, stack-overflow

I have some code running in my While loop:

```
while (Time <= EndPeriod)
{
      ... code ...

      Tine.AddTime(Time);
}
```

The problem I am having is where Time.AddTime(Time) executes it creates a memory leak. The AddTime function checks a class property and adds time via the correct method (e.g. AddDays, AddMonths, etc...) based on the DateFormat variable in a switch. If I put the switch into the loop everything is fine, however if I try to reference this function it does a stack overflow.

My AddTime function is below:

```
protected DateTime AddTime(DateTime Time)
{
    DateTime myTime = Time;
    switch (DatePart) {
        case "yy":
            myTime.AddYears(1);
            break;
        case "qq":
            myTime.AddDays(1);
            break;
        case "mm":
            myTime.AddMonths(1);
            break;
        case "dd":
            myTime.AddDays(1);
            break;
        case "hh":
            myTime.AddHours(1);
            break;
        case "ss":
            myTime.AddSeconds(1);
            break;
        default:
            myTime.AddMinutes(1);
            break;
    }
    return myTime;
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you really have two different properties/fields `Tine` and `Time`? (`Tine.AddTime(Time);`)

Comment: Out of memory, eh? Where do you give value to `EndPeriod`? Also, what's `DatePart`? Seems we don't have the whole picture here. Why do you never assign back to `myTime`?

Comment: Out of memory, or stack overflow? They're two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change:

```
myTime.AddSeconds(1);
```

to

```
// The same for all other methods which considered to modify 
// a DateTime value including your custom AddTime() method
myTime = myTime.AddSeconds(1);
```

In this way condition a value of `Time` would be changes so you have a chance that condition `(Time <= EndPeriod)` will be passed ever.

All methods like [DateTime.AddYears()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx) [DateTime.AddDays()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) does not modify a value of object itself but returns new value.

MSDN:

> This method does not change the value of this DateTime object.
>   Instead, it returns a new DateTime object whose value is the result of
>   this operation.

Comment: Same goes for the `Tine.AddTime(Time)`

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the stack is overflowing from numerous DateTime allocations. Try moving the DateTime outside of the loop & constantly overwriting it.

The thought here is that b/c DateTime is allocated to the stack rather than heap it may cause the caling thead (while loop) to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming a typo on the code and correcting it here...

```
Time.AddTime(Time);
```

Does this modify `Time`?  Doesn't look like it, at least not intuitively.  If you're not changing the value of `Time` then the loop is going to run endlessly, never reaching its terminating condition.  Try assigning the return value:

```
Time = Time.AddTime(Time);
```

Additionally, inside of the method where you use things like `myTime.AddYears()` and other such methods, you need to assign their return values to your variable as well.

As a general matter of design you should be careful with which methods modify which objects.  I admit that the `.AddXX()` methods on `DateTime` aren't very intuitive in that regard.